# How to force display of that banner message in Julia's REPL?

Tags: julia, read-eval-print-loop

Just out of sheer curiosity, is there a way to intentionally display that banner message that one sees at startup of the Julia REPL?

When querying `help?` I got this:

```
help?> banner
search: AbstractChannel

Couldn't find banner
Perhaps you meant base, Channel, Range, range or Base
ERROR: "banner" is not defined in module Main
  in error at error.jl:21
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost got it though. `banner` is not exported by the `Base` module. All you need is to call `Base.banner()` on the REPL instead.

Comment: A-ha! Cheers, @ShaoWei!

Comment: Cheers @buruzaemon =)